# Prove that for every sufficiently large n, exists a k-paradoxical tournament on n vertices

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I need to prove that for every $n \ge r_k = 2\cdot2^k\cdot k^2$
there exists a k-paradoxical tournament on n vertices.

I found a probabilistic proof that shows that if it holds that
$\frac{1}{k!}n^k(1- \frac{1}{2^k})^{n-k} \le 1$

then there exists a k-paradoxical tournament on n vertices. (The proof can be found here: [example of a probabilistic proof](https://planetmath.org/exampleofaprobabilisticproof).)

But I'm having a hard time to show that for every $n \ge r_k $ , this inequality holds.

Anyone has any ideas? maybe this is not the right way to prove this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi -- welcome to math.SE! Please make the question self-contained. [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a reference and tutorial for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: I've replaced the broken link to PlanetMath.org with one to a "topic page" there. These were apparently converted from the PDF files with some loss of clarity, but a patient Reader should be able to grasp the context.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n=2^{k+1}k^2$.

Using the inequalities ${n \choose r} \leq {\left(\frac{en}{r}\right)}^{r}$ and $1-x \leq e^{-x}$ for the first and second terms respectively, we get that it is sufficient to prove:

$ {(e2^{k+1}k)}^{k}e^{-k^2} <1 $,
which reduces to showing $e2^{k+1}k<e^k$, which is true for large enough $k$.